# How can I log into file and on console at the same time with "tee" command?

Tags: python, powershell, logging, tee

I'm executing a python file with powershell and I would like to get the log in a file and on console also, so tried to use the *tee* command.

```
cd folder
.\program.py | tee log.txt
```

But error was thrown back

```
Cannot run a document in the middle of a pipeline
```

Python file just contains 1 line of code

```
print "test"
```

How can I use this command at the right way?

Comment: Do you have `python` files registered correctly to be using `.\program.py` syntax?

Comment: Do you have a conflicting executable, `tee.exe` in your `$Env:PATH`?

Comment: If I just want to execute the program by .\program.py - it is okay, don't have conflicting exe

Comment: To complement the effective solutions below: as @MaximilianBurszley hints at, the implication of your symptom that Python scripts aren't considered directly executable on your system, which in turn implies that there is no `.PY` entry in your `PATHEXT` environment variable (`$env:PATHEXT`  shows its value).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call python to execute the script.
Try executing in the folder where program.py and log.txt is:

```
python program.py | tee log.txt
```

The explanation is that ./program.py without python command tries to run or open the file, but you are not executing it. Then, you try to to pass the ouput to log.txt with the pipe operator and tee. So it is the expected behaviour.

Aditionally, you are using python 2 syntax which is deprecated since ages. Try using print("test") inside the script.

Answer (score 3):

Use `python` before `.\program.py` and also use `Tee-Object` in powerShell .

```
python .\program.py | Tee-Object -FilePath log.txt
```

Comment: Good advice to use `Tee-Object` for clarity. On Windows, `tee` is a built-in alias for `Tee-Object`, so its use is safe there, but on Unix-like platforms PowerShell doesn't define this alias, because it doesn't want to shadow (override) the standard `tee` Unix utility (`/usr/bin/tee`).